# Аутентификация в codeception

Tags: php

Делаю тест на аутентификацию. Создал простую форму.

```html
<div>Hello</div>
    <form>
        <div>
            <label for="UserEmail"> login <br>
                <input id="UserEmail">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label> password <br>
                <input id="UserPassword">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit">
        </div>
    </form>
```

Тест на то, что страница работает - проходит

Тест на аутентификацию - нет

```
    <?php
  $I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
  $I->amOnPage('/test.html');
  $I->fillField('UserEmail', 'y.gluschenkov@aaa.ru');
  $I->fillField('UserPassword', '123698745aZ');
  $I->click('Enter');
```

Пробовал так
Ошибка, что не найден CSS элемент или label

```
    <?php
  $I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
  $I->amOnPage('/test.html');
  $I->fillField("//input[@id='UserEmail']", 'y.gluschenkov@aaa.ru');
  $I->fillField("//input[@id='UserPassword']", '123698745aZ');
  $I->click('Enter');
```

Результат тот же

```
    1) WelcomeCept (tests/acceptance//WelcomeCept.php)

 Step  I fill field "UserEmail","y.gluschenkov@aaa.ru"
 Fail  Form field by Label or CSS 'UserEmail' was not found.

Scenario Steps:

 2. $I->fillField("UserEmail","y.gluschenkov@aaa.ru")
 1. $I->amOnPage("/test.html")


FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Failures: 1.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. У вас нет теста на то что страница корректно загружена, вы могли получить другую страницу или 404. Пример правильного теста $I->see('Hello');
2. У инпутов нет name, по нему проще всего заполнять форму, к тому же он все равно понадобится для отправки формы
3. У сабмита нет value, вы не сможете кликнуть по нему

Исправленный тест:

```
<div>Hello</div>
<form>
    <div>
        <label for="UserEmail"> login <br>
            <input name="UserEmail" id="UserEmail">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label> password <br>
            <input name="UserPassword" id="UserPassword">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Enter">
    </div>
</form>
```

```
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
$I->amOnPage('/test.html');
$I->see('Hello');
$I->fillField('UserEmail', 'y.gluschenkov@aaa.ru');
$I->fillField('UserPassword', '123698745aZ');
$I->click('Enter');
```

Comment: На тесте выяснилось, что его перекидывает на странницу прокси. 
Ошибки нет, так как сделал export прокси. А вот как сделать, чтоб переходил на заданную страницу, не подскажите?

Сделал  

'class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - PhpBrowser:
            url: 'http://rabota.mysite.loc/'
            proxy: {192.168.0.1:80}
            proxyAuth: {y.glushenkov:iiii}
        - \Helper\Acceptance'

Но не помогло

Comment: добавить http:// к адресу rabota.mysite.loc

Comment: http:// помог

А еще убрал

#proxy: http://192.168.0.1:8080
            #proxyType: http
            #proxyAuth: y.glushenkov:iiii

И убрал прокси 

export http_proxy=""

Так как для локальных он не нужен, т.е. ошибка, отчасти, была в том, что был прописан прокси, а он не нужен был:)

Comment: А возможно ли тестировать динамические созданые html? Т.е., например, форму созданную через js?

Comment: Можно с помощью codeception webdrvier + phantomjs или селениум, [инструкция](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver)

Answer (score 1):

Решил таким путем

```
<?php

class AcceptanceTester extends \Codeception\Actor
{
    use _generated\AcceptanceTesterActions;

    public function login($name, $password, $param){
        $I = $this;
        $I->amOnPage('/');
        $I->submitForm('#container', [
            'username-container' => $name,
            'password-container' => $password
        ]);
        //$I->see($param);
    }
}
$Codeception = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
$Codeception->login('y.gluschenkov@aaa.ru', '123698745aZ', 'Панель управления');
```